# firewall makes 20 secs delay on rtmp flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, rtmp

Hi have a player that works over firewall using rtmp packets on port 1935. The problem I get is the streaming starts 20 seconds after I start the player.

What could be causing this problem.

When firewall is off the player starts to stream right away from the openning.

Comment: Sounds like network lag; perhaps the firewall is parsing each packet somehow?

Comment: I tried this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2918563/flvplayback.swf to stream and it works well i.d it streams good even if the firewall is on. So I am guessing the player has some problem. What shoudl I add to AS3 code to stream over rtmp on port 1935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the player gets hostname instead of the ip address for streaming so it was struggling for 20 secs to do that. Ok we found that the DNS wasn't resolving the url for streaming properly :) So use real ip address to stream instead of hostname

Answer (score 1):

Flash players on RTMP have a fallback chain in which they attempt to connect at TCP:1935 and if that fails, try TCP:80. This fallback chain could take a while, especially if your firewall drops 1935 packets instead of rejecting them.

If you have access to the firewall configuration, try to change the 1935 policy to either allow or reject (but not drop).

Otherwise, if you can modify the HTML, you can try to change to RTMP link URL schema to be "rtmpt://" instead of "rtmp://". This will cause the player to attempt port 80 right away (though, when RTMP on port 1935 works, it works better than RTMPT on port 80).

Comment: Do I miss something in my code for rtmp on 1935? i have implemented standard as3 netconnection and netstream for rtmp and the player works good but when the firwall is on it makes 20 secs lag until starts streaming

Comment: If you're opening an "rtmp://" resource in as3, and port 1935 can't connect, it will attempt to reconnect on port 80 (without requiring that you explicitly code anything for that). If you use "rtmpt://" it will force the connection to be on port 80 from the beginning.